# Mongo not using index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following indexes within a collection:

```
db.JobStatusModel.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "jobs.JobStatusModel"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "peopleId" : 1,
            "jobId" : 1
        },
        "name" : "peopleId_jobId_compounded",
        "ns" : "jobs.JobStatusModel"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "jobId" : 1
        },
        "name" : "jobId_1",
        "ns" : "jobs.JobStatusModel",
        "background" : true
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "peopleId" : 1,
            "disInterested" : 1
        },
        "name" : "peopleId_1_disInterested_1",
        "ns" : "jobs.JobStatusModel",
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

Trying to work out some slow running queries running against the compound indexes, however, even simple queries aren't making use of indexes:

```
db.JobStatusModel.find({ jobId : '1f940601ff7385931ec04dca88c853dd' }).explain(true)
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor jobId_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 221,
    "nscannedObjects" : 221,
    "nscanned" : 221,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 221,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 221,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "jobId" : [
            [
                "1f940601ff7385931ec04dca88c853dd",
                "1f940601ff7385931ec04dca88c853dd"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "allPlans" : [
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor jobId_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 221,
            "nscannedObjects" : 221,
            "nscanned" : 221,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "jobId" : [
                    [
                        "1f940601ff7385931ec04dca88c853dd",
                        "1f940601ff7385931ec04dca88c853dd"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "server" : "mongo3.pilot.dice.com:27017",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "FETCH",
        "works" : 222,
        "yields" : 1,
        "unyields" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 221,
        "needTime" : 0,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "forcedFetches" : 0,
        "matchTested" : 0,
        "children" : [
            {
                "type" : "IXSCAN",
                "works" : 222,
                "yields" : 1,
                "unyields" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 221,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : "{ jobId: 1.0 }",
                "isMultiKey" : 0,
                "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['jobId']: [\"1f940601ff7385931ec04dca88c853dd\", \"1f940601ff7385931ec04dca88c853dd\"]",
                "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 0,
                "keysExamined" : 221,
                "children" : [ ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

as we can see from the output I am getting the `"indexOnly" : false,` from the output meaning it cannot just do an index scan even though my field is indexed. How can I ensure queries are running only against indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be sure you get indexOnly you need to return only those fields from the index, use [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection-document):

```
db.collection.find( <query filter>, <projection> )

db.JobStatusModel.find({ jobId : '1f940601ff7385931ec04dca88c853dd' }, {jobId:1, _id:0})
```

Answer (score 4):

> even simple queries aren't making use of indexes:

Your query **did** use an index as indicated by the `IXSCAN` stage and index cursor  (`"cursor" : "BtreeCursor jobId_1",`).

> Trying to work out some slow running queries running against the compound indexes, however,

Based on the provided `getIndexes()` output, your query on the single field `jobId` only has one candidate index to consider:  `{jobId:1}`. This query ran in 1 millisecond (`"millis" : 1`) and returned 221 documents looking at 221 index keys -- an ideal 1:1 hit ratio for key comparisons to matches.

The compound index of `{peopleId:1, jobId:1}` would only be considered if you also provided a `peopleId` value in your query. However, you could potentially create a compound index with these fields in the opposite order if you sometimes query solely on `jobId` but also frequently query on both `peopleId` and `jobId`. A compound index on `{jobId:1, peopleId:1}` would obviate the need for the `{jobId:1}` index since it could satisfy the same queries.

For more information see [Create Indexes to Support Your Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/) in the MongoDB manual and the blog post [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/).

Note: You haven't mentioned what version of MongoDB server you are using but the format of your `explain()` output indicates that you're running an older version of MongoDB that has reached End-of-Life (i.e. anything older than MongoDB 3.0 as at Jan-2017). I strongly recommend upgrading to a newer and supported version (eg. MongoDB 3.2 or 3.4) as there are significant improvements. End-of-Life server release series are no longer maintained and may potentially expose your application to known bugs and vulnerabilities that have been addressed in subsequent production releases.

> as we can see from the output I am getting the `"indexOnly" : false,` from the output meaning it cannot just do an index scan even though my field is indexed. How can I ensure queries are running only against indexes?

The `indexOnly` value will only be `true` in the special case of a [*covered query*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query). A covered query is one where all of the fields in the query are part of an index *and* all of the fields projected in the results are in the same index. Typically indexed queries are not covered: index lookups are used to find matching documents which are then retrieved and filtered to the fields requested in the query projection.